# The map $f:S^1 \to S^1, f(z) = z^k$ is well-defined only if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Is the map $f:S^1 \to S^1, f(z) = z^k$ well-defined only if $k$ is an integer?

I believe that $k$ needs to be at least a rational number, because $(-1)^k$ is not really defined when $k$ is irrational. However, I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has $n$ $n$th roots for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: Oh yes...I completely did not think about that for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean well-defined? For any complex number $z\neq 0$, you can definitely define a complex number $\theta_z$ such that $z=\exp(i\theta_z)$ and define $z^k=\exp(k \theta_z)$, which could be made perfectly well-defined. Do you want the map to satisfy some properties like continuity or something else?

Comment: I was thinking of this function as a "loop" on the circle, so I think I should assume continuity.

Comment: How is it not well defined?

Answer (score -1):

You need $k$ to be an integer for $f(e^{0i})=f(e^{2\pi i})$. And this equality needs to hold for well-defined-ness.